# iPhone SDK Xcode - How to get all the filenames in the documents dir

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to get all the filenames in my application's `documents` folder, and place them in an `NSMutableArray`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a convenient method in `NSFileManager`:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory 
                                                  error:nil];
...
[fileManager release];
```

As of ARC you can of course drop the release statement.

Comment: Rather than `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` you should use `[[NSFileManager alloc] init]` which returns a thread safe NSFileManager instance.

Comment: This snippet of code is going to be copied and pasted for years - it might as well be up to date.