# Remove all files from memory using NSFileManager

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can you remove all the files that are saved using the `NSFileManager` ? I found something like the code below, but you need to give the filePath and since I need to delete all the images that I've saved, I don't know all the image paths/names?

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064190/iphone-sdk-xcode-how-to-get-all-the-filenames-in-the-documents-dir

Comment: Walk the directories and find what you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

First get all the item from that particular folder :

```
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your folder path where you have saved those images"];
NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath 
                                                  error:nil];
```

this will be the array of the files just loop through the array .and use:

```
  for(NSString *filename in files)
   {
    NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"filepath/%@",filename];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
   }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried this but [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL]; returns NO which means there was an error

Comment: This is the error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)

Comment: NSFileNoSuchFileError = 4,        // Attempt to do a file system operation on a non-existent file

Comment: @Shinonuma: You have to give path of the folder while getting the array of the files. if you want to delete the files from the temp folder then give a path of the temp folder . For more info just check the SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378768/how-to-select-all-the-images-from-my-iphone-app-document-directory/14378884#14378884

Answer (score 0):

You must be saving your images to any of the folders like, Documents Directory, Library, Caches, or Temp folders. You need to fetch all the images inside any of your directory where you have saved your images using following code..

```
-(NSArray*)getImagesFromDirectory:(NSString*)imageDirectoryPath{

   NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
   NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:imageDirectoryPath 
                                          error:nil];
   return files;
}
```

Then loop to remove images at path

```
 NSArray *images=[self getImagesFromDirectory:@"DIRECTORYPATH"];
 NSFileManager * fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 for(NSString *imagePath in images){
     [fileManager removeItemAtPath:imagePath];
 }
```